# Change user AND environment in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Why does this work (as root):

```
$su - aba
~> echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Ausgabe: `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45`

And not this shell script (also run as root):

```
#!/bin/bash
su - aba << EOF
echo $JAVA_HOME > tmp
EOF
```

Output:

```
$more tmp

$
```

**Question:**
How can I make this work? Or better: My goal is to execute some commands as another user and also use this enviroment of this user and maybe even change his enviroment (only temporary).

**EDIT**
In the meantime I succeeded with `runuser - aba -c 'echo JAVA_HOME'`, altough it's not in all aspects what wished for, because I still can only transfer one command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su - aba`

is short for

`su --login ada`

which doesn't make sense inside a script. Since you don't have a terminal once it is run it goes back to the previous user (root).

try

`su -c "echo $JAVA_HOME" ada`

but even this won't run the users .profile or .bashrc.

However you are root and you should be able to parse those files for the proper settings.

eg.

`TEMP_JAVA=$(grep JAVA_HOME /home/$USER/.bashrc)

JAVA_HOME=${TEMP_JAVA##*=}
echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Ok, grep is a good idea. I can work with that. In the meantime I also succeeded with runuser - aba -c command.

Comment: I would vote you up, but I'm a newbie here and and not allowed to ;-)

Comment: Find some Java stuff and answer. I was doing the same with bash stuff.  Already made upvote stage, have reached comments on Unix&Linux.